# Inverse Laplace transform of $\frac{\left( s - |\lambda| \right)^{\alpha} }{\left( s + |\lambda|\right)^{\alpha+1}} $

Tags: analysis, laplace-transform

I would like to ask you to help me determining the following inverse Laplace transform:

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{\left( s - |\lambda| \right)^{\alpha} }{\left( s + |\lambda|\right)^{\alpha+1}} \right)$ = ?

where $\alpha$ is a positive real number, $\lambda$ is a real number, and the inverse Laplace transform is square integrable.

**What I do not know**, is the answer.

**What I know** is as follows:

1. According to Oberhettinger, p. 239, Eq. (4.15)

$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{\left( s - |\lambda| \right)^{\nu} }{\left( s + |\lambda|\right)^{\mu}} \right) = (2 \lambda)^{(-\nu+\mu)/2} (\Gamma(\nu))^{-1} x^{(-\mu+\nu)/2-1} M_{(\mu+\nu)/2 , (\mu-\nu-1)/2}(2\lambda x) $

if $Re\left(\mu-\nu \right)>0$

This solution is, however, not square integrable.

2. If $\alpha \in N$, then we get the Laguerre functions.
3. I implemented Peter den Iseger's inverse Laplace transform algorithm to check, if the solution exists. For the Bromwich integral I chose a path $s: s= 0.089 + i y, y = -\infty ... \infty$. I experienced, that

=> for $\alpha \in N$ is the real part, indeed, the Laguerre function of order $n$, and the imaginary part is zero ( modulo num noise)

=> for $\alpha \in R, \notin N$ I get the following set of functions, parameterised with $\alpha$:

[Result of numerical inverse Laplace transform of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNcrM.jpg)

As we see, indeed, the solutions are square integrable and converge to the Laguerre functions of integer order, if $\alpha \rightarrow \alpha_N$

Thx in advance.

Comment: The rhs of the entry 4.15 from [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65645-3) is
$$\frac {(2 a)^{(\nu - \mu)/2}} {\Gamma(\mu - \nu)}
 t^{(\mu - \nu)/2 - 1} M_{(\mu + \nu)/2, (\mu - \nu - 1)/2}(2 a t).$$
It can be derived from the LT of ${_1 \hspace {-1 px} F_1}(a; b; t)$. Note that the rightmost singularity of your $F(s)$ is located at $|\lambda|$ if $\alpha \not \in \mathbb N^0$ and at $-|\lambda|$ otherwise.

Comment: @maxim. Thanks for the answer. 
1. Indeed, there is a sign error in t^{(\mu-\nu)/2-1}, what I wrote.
2. However, the asymptotics Whittaker M(x) ~exp(x), thus it will not be square integrable  x \in R.
3. If x is a pure imaginary, then the  inverse transform will exhibit infinitly many zeros ( by the \exp(i x) ), which are equally spaced, thus its behaviour is different from the functions I attached to this post.

Comment: Note that the factor $(2 a)^{(\nu - \mu)/2}/\Gamma(\mu - \nu)$ is also different. The growth rate of $\mathcal L^{-1}[F]$ is related to the location of the singularities of $F$, $\mathcal L^{-1}[s \mapsto 1/(s - 1)]$ is not in $L^2$ either. The Bromwich integral of $F$ converges only for $x \in \mathbb R$. $L^{-1}[F](x)$ shows oscillatory behavior but with finite number of oscillations.